# How to use history.back()

Tags: javascript

can i do the following?

window.open(“any url”, “_self”)

history.back()

I want to go to the other page and then return to previous one, but this aproach doesn't work. Is this impossible, and history.back()  can't be used this way, because the scripts on the new page get loaded instead of the old one?
Also, i tried to do the window.open on one page and do history back from the other, it still doesn't work...

Comment: Both lines are on the same page?

Comment: Yes, they are on the same page

Comment: Both are ways of navigating to another page, so the browser can't do both at the same time. If you wanted to do something after the first navigation you would have to wait until that has happened, but then the script that would do something is gone.

Comment: So, how do i go to the other page and then return back to previous one?

Comment: what browser have you tried?

Comment: I tried Google Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the browser did the relocation faster, than it stored the previous page in history, when i wrapped window.open() (the first page) and history.goBack() (the other page)  with functions and called them with button onclick it worked. '

 Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You may like to use history.go(-1) This will be more effective and generic, and will give you added advantage to go back further than the previous page. thanks

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't answer the question.